# How to send Typescript variable in a jquery call back function?

Tags: jquery, angular, nodes

I have a jquery callback function in an angular 6 component. In that component there is a typescript variable. When a click event is triggered on the web page , the callback function will be called.But I want to send the typescript variable in the callback function too. How to do that?

```
export class A implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit() {
   this.initJquery();
    }
   private modalSelector = ''; // Typescript variable
   initJquery() {
      $(document).click(function(e) {
       console.log(this.modalSelector);
     });
   }
}
```

But  `console.log(this.modalSelector)`; is printing `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using arrow functions.

In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`. Read [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions)

```
initJquery() {
  $(document).click((e) => {
    console.log(this.modalSelector);
  });
}
```